# Do individuals with the power of Titans posses the ability to time travel through the memories of future wielders of Titan powers?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In episode 21 of season 3, Eren Kruger

> who is The Owl (Former Attack Titan), told Grisha to save Mikasa and Armin despite the fact that they were not even born at that time.

How could he

> access the memories of a future Attack Titan?

Is this an ability available to

> all Titan shifters?

If so, then why was Eren Kruger the first to manifest it?

Comment: That's a given ability, that Titan shifters possess memories from the future and past wielders of the Titan it currently has. The specifics were never explained in the manga and I'm not sure it will ever be, given how far it is already from that revelation and the fact that it's already in the final arc. But there is no time travel involved, they only see what will happen or was happened in the future and past, respectively.

Comment: it was never explicitly stated that they can access the memories of future titan shifters, @W.Are we are only sure about seeing the  memories of previous ones. Except maybe i missed something?

Comment: It seems to me that what happened in Eren Kreugers case was as a result of something more complex, otherwise, many other titan shifters would have been known to have used such an ability.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Eren Krueger's case is proof that some, if not all, Titan shifters can access memories of future inheritors of Titan shifters. Otherwise, how would he know about Armin and Mikasa? You're right that it's never fully explained and I was wrong with the wordings I used. Whether or not it is unique to the attack titan, we'll never know for now but the attack titan do have access to future memories. To what extent was never specified too.

Comment: It's possible that what we see is either some of Eren's own thoughts corrupting the memory he was viewing. In the same way that viewing the memory acted on Eren's body, making him stand in a particular way and repeat the name "Attack Titan".

Comment: It's also possible that eventually Attack on Titan will introduce the [Wheel of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_of_time) concept and reveal these memories to be the distant past from the last time this all happened, rather than the future.

Answer (score 1):

not all titans posses this ability but it is an unique ability to Eren's titan,So therefore anyone with the Eren's titan power can do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the **Attack titan** special power,
which Eren possesses

> welders of Attack titan can see the future and control the past just like what Eren is about to do in season 4.