# Why does Grisha Yeager have to love someone?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In attack on Titan ep 58, Eren  Kruger says that Grisha has to love someone inside the walls or else “history will repeat itself”.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Probably "love" means have a child.  Mold the child's thinking and the child inherit the attacking titan with the same ideals of them. Maybe if he doesn't pass the power, the power would be lost and some new baby would inherited the power. It could also mean that in the past, maybe the attacking titan was lost during a fight and then a new born inherited the power. Which could explain how Marley only had 7/9 powers,  Padaris had 1/9, the attacking titan was lost, and somehow Kruger was given that power. Pretty much no one knew that Kruger had Yrmi's blood in him.  Maybe that caused a problem and made history repeat itself. 
There are different translations, I recall only to get married start a new family, and continue the mission to find the royal family and their power. I thinks that the family was just to fit in better, and child to pass the power.

Answer (score 0):

There are hints in AoT that time is cyclical. The most obvious of these are actually in other questions on the site.

[Eren Kruger](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/53389/do-individuals-with-the-power-of-titans-posses-the-ability-to-time-travel-throug) tells Grisha about people who haven't been born yet.

[Zeke](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28797/are-there-more-titan-shifters-unknown-as-of-now/49504#49504) talks to Riener and Bertholdt.

Finally Armin and Eren's obsession with seeing the sea, and their certainty (that comes up several times) that they will see it together.

If AoT time is cyclical, then the events of the series have already played out before, possibly many times, and keep recurring in the devastating pattern portrayed in the series. Kruger may be imperfectly remembering details from a previous iteration of history and giving Grisha advice on actions that may lead to a better future.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer and it's the very closest.

The ability to transfer titan powers is by having an Eldian transform into a titan and eat a titan shifter. Because Grisha is the only one who has this knowledge within the walls, only he knows how to transfer his abilities. Kruger believes that having a child inherit Grisha’s abilities would be the best way, and so, instructs Grisha to marry someone and produce a child, henceforth, Eren Yeager.

The Link

> https://www.quora.com/In-Attack-On-Titan-why-does-Grisha-Yeager-have-to-love-someone